# migrating mysql instance on AWS RDS - mysql is not an option

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

I have an instance in RDS that is using mysql as the database engine.  When I try to migrate that instance to a new one, it is only giving me options for Aurora and MariaDB.  A few weeks ago I did the same thing to make a test version of the production database instance, and mysql was an option then.  Any ideas on how I can make a copy of a mysql instance?

Comment: Isn't restoring from an RDS snapshot a simpler option?

Comment: I just tried the Migrate Snapshot option and it too is only offering aurora and mariadb even though the instance currently uses mysql.

Comment: In the RDS console, navigate to a previous snaphot, and choose Actions | Restore Snapshot. I'm guessing that you are in the DMS console.

Comment: "Migrate" implies converting from one thing to another. What are you trying to migrate the server to exactly? What is the end goal you are trying to accomplish? If you are just trying to "copy" the server then you need to restore a snapshot, not migrate a server.

Comment: I'm trying to create a copy of the mysql instance in a new instance to use for test purposes.

Comment: Thanks, Mark B!  The restore option is working!  My bad.  If you add that as an answer I'll be sure to give you credit!

Comment: I guess third time's the charm ;-)